# how to call a variable outside of click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

jquery

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
var $myvar = 'hi';
});

alert($myvar); // this won't alert hi as this is out of click function
```

How can I call that $myvar outside the function?

---

**Update**

I tried with below answers but seems not working http://jsfiddle.net/G5vAv/1/

I would like to return the value 'hi' when alerting. Any idea?

Comment: the problem is the variable is in the local scope of the function the solution is to move it a shared scope between the `click` handler and the consumer of the variable

Comment: You're telling it to be hi only when you click so it's not going to be hi unless you click.

Comment: That's what I want to call any idea please!!

Comment: You are assigning value to $myvar on click so it will show 'undefined' on load after you click your variable it is assigned to hi, or try this way http://jsfiddle.net/G5vAv/3/

Comment: I have to call without click but that variable is from click function. So is there no any idea to extract the value from click function.

Comment: You can trigger a click like this http://jsfiddle.net/G5vAv/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myvar;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
   $myvar = 'hi';
});
alert($myvar);
```

By using var inside the click function you are setting `$myvar` as a `local variable` which is only accessible inside the click function.

To make your variable accessible outside you have to declare it outside.

More about it [javascript-variable-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable outside the function like so

```
var $myvar;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    $myvar = 'hi';
});

alert($myvar);
```

This happens because of the different scopes in javascript, your variable was applied to the function's scope and the alert is outside that scope and therefore unable to access it.

All you have to remember is that javascript looks up for variables not down so you can only access variables that are declared on the current level or higher here is some examples.

```
var level_1;

// I can access level 1

function somefunc() {
   var level_2;
   // I can access levels 1 & 2


   return function() {
      var level_3;
      // I can access levels 1, 2 & 3 
   }
}
```

Comment: @C-Link That's because the default value for a variable is `undefined` if you alert it after you click then you will see the value like this http://jsfiddle.net/G5vAv/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can't, since you are setting `$myvar` inside the function, it is limited to the scope of that function. if you want to be able to access the variable outside of the function, you can either:

1. leave out the `var` keyword, which will make it a global variable, or
2. define it outside of the function:

```
var $myvar;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    $myvar = 'hi';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `$myvar` outside of the function

```
var $myvar;
$('#click').on('click',function(){
    $myvar = 'hi';
    checknow();
    return false;
});

function checknow()
{
    alert($myvar);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G5vAv/)

Comment: is it possible to show without function call?